# Doesn't append to head of list create a new list in erlang?

Tags: erlang

In erlang everything is immutable right? So how does appending an element to the head of list not create a new copy of the list where as using append creates a new copy each time?

Quote from erlang.org:
When recursing and building a list, it is important to ensure that you attach the new elements to the beginning of the list. In this way, you will build one list, not hundreds or thousands of copies of the growing result list.

Isn't traversing the linked list each time the reason for not appending at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erlang uses single linked list for lists. Adding head doesn't modify tail. Imagine you have list `T = [10, 50, 40]`. Adding head is `[20 | T]` and a result looks like on the picture. You can see that `[10, 50, 40]` part is not altered.

[image]

Comment: I want know why "++" for list is not a good way? Could you give a detail explaniation?

Comment: The last node in a list has a NULL reference to the "next" node (which, obviously, doesn't exist for the last node.) When two lists are joined, one of the list's last node needs to refer to the start of the second list. Since data is immutable in Erlang, a new last node has to be created to point to the start of the other list. Then the next-to-last node has to point to the new "last" node. To summarize: in `a ++ b`, `a` will have to be completely copied to the front of `b`. And the original `a` will not have been modified at all.